# ASP.NET подгрузка файлов при старте сервера

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

В общем. Есть проект ASP.NET MVC. В папке проекта, дополнительно к шаблонному проекту, есть ещё одна папка. В этой папке находятся файлы формата json, .js и ещё всякие другие ресурсы. Так вот, как подгрузить файлы формата .js и css при помощи bundlow я знаю, а как мне подгружать всё остальное(при старте самого сервера)?

Comment: Что такое "все остальное"? Куда подгружать? Ели "все остальное" это данные - просто вызовите соответствующий контроллер при загрузку страницы. Пока из текста вопроса не понятно что, куда и зачем вы собрались подгружать.

Comment: Всё остальное, это ресурсы, ну или "данные", у меня траблы с фреймов extJs, он при инициализации(на странице выполняется скрипт js) ищет файл classic.json, которого там, нет, т.к я не знаю как его добавить на сам сервер

Comment: А почему в вопросе нет ни слова про extJs?

Comment: потому что вопрос общий, и связан с любыми файлами на сервере, а проблема с ExtJs, скорее частный случай, нежели сама проблема